# How to solve a system of linear ODEs with distinct time conditions?

Tags: python, matlab, ode

I am interested in solving the following system of ODEs

```py
x′=2x+3y+z
y′=x−3y+2z
z′=x+2y−4z
```

with conditions at *distinct times*, even at *time at infinity*.

```py
x(0)=1
y(0)=1
z(+inf)=0
```

I tried to google but it seems to be no method in PYTHON, MATLAB suitable for this system. Are there any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: down-vote for no reason?! hix hix?!

Comment: Do you want to do something similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57262/how-to-solve-ode-with-boundary-at-infinity) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884557/solve-differential-equation-with-infinite-boundary-condition-in-matlab)?

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting or make it obvious with a preference of where the answers should go. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053768/numerically-solving-a-system-of-linear-odes-with-different-time-conditions

Comment: @Vicky thank for your help, they are not exactly the same as we have to consider a system here. I found that many libraries in both python and matlab are only available for system without conditions or one equation with conditions.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry I will learn from experience! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this make sense, mathematically speaking. ODE solvers start from a set of initial conditions. There isn't necessarily a unique solution to an ODE when your constraints are not all defined at the same start time.

Imagine an ODE which converges to a steady-state condition no matter the initial condition. If all you hand the solver is the final condition (at infinity time), what info does it have to divine the initial conditions?